# Cascading ComboBoxes

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to create a cascading `ComboBox` that is populated from a SQL data set.
My problem is I am not getting any errors when compiling the code. but the two ComboBoxes are not populating as intended with data. Can you help me find where I am making the mistake?

```vb
Private Sub FillSalesPerson()
    Dim strConnString As String
    strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ConnectionString
    Dim DS As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = DS
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "select distinct Name,Salesperson_Code  from dbo.View_Customers_With_Sales_People"
    Dim objeDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim dAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    DS.Open()
    dAdapter.Fill(objeDS)
    DS.Close()

    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Salesperson_Code"
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = objeDS.Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() <> " " Then
        Dim Salesperson_Code As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
        FillStates(Salesperson_Code)
        'ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0'
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillStates(Salesperson_Code As Integer)
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ConnectionString
    Dim DS As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = DS
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "Select [No_],[Company Name] from [dbo].[View_Customers_With_Sales_People] where (Salesperson_Code= @Salesperson_Code)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salesperson_Code", Salesperson_Code)
    Dim objDs As New DataSet()
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    DS.Open()
    adapter.Fill(objDs)
    DS.Close()
    If objDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "[No_]"
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "[Company Name]"
        ComboBox2.DataSource = objDs.Tables(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "not populating as intended" mean? No data? Wrong data? Slow?

Comment: Combo boxes are not populating  with data. They are empty after compiling thanks

Comment: If there are no exceptions being thrown, then I suspect your queries just return no rows.

Comment: No exception thrown, that's  the problem. Cant find why its not working.Ran the sql query in sq serverl.it works perfectly

Comment: Sql query gives results with data when run on sql server

Comment: After you call `Fill` you can put a break point, hover over the dataset, and it will let you see the contents. Working in SSMS is not the same as working in code. Also, since `objDs` is global, make sure your clear it or choose the correct table. It might not be table at index zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `ComboBox1.DataSource = objeDS.Tables(0)` for `ComboBox1.RowSource = objeDS.Tables(0)`